# How do you change the UIButon text attribute in a custom UITableViewCell in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have seen many posts about this subject but I could not find one that is suitable to solve my exact situation. I have a UITableView that contains a Custom UITableViewCell with a UIButton and UITextfield. I can catch the button press with the following code in my UITableView Delegate:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ConversationCell";

    ConversationCell *cell = (ConversationCell *)[tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
       NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ConversationCell" owner:self options:nil];
       cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    [cell.participantBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(editClickedParticipant:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   return cell;
}
```

Then adding the following method to process the click

```
- (void) editClickedParticipant:(id) sender
{
    ...
}
```

In editClickedParticipant I show a UIPickerView with a list of choices. Once the index from the picker is selected how do I change the button's text attribute in the cell that triggered the editClickedParticipant action ? Is there a way to use a tag or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This could be easily done using `tag` property:**

`cell.participantBtn.tag = indexPath.row; // This goes in cellForRowAIndexPath method`

```
- (void) editClickedParticipant:(id) sender {

   NSInteger row = sender.tag; //Anything can be done with the button
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: row inSection:0];

   //Change your button's text attribute here below
   [sender setTitle:@"Your new title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the button using:

```
UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
```

And apply changes in your senderButton.

Or,
If you need the cell,

```
- (void) editClickedParticipant:(id) sender {
   CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
//You can get the cell and other components inside the cell using indexPath
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying your change in button text in the view controller lifecycle method of `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`

This is the appropriate place/time in the view controller lifecycle to adjust the views within a cell - just before it is displayed.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    'for example...

    cell.participantBtn.label = "new label";
}
```

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference?language=objc)...

> This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based
>   properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and
>   background color. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only
>   the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as
>   they slide in or out.